# nslookup works but network no

Tags: networking, server, iptables

System information:

ubuntu server CLI only 22.04.3 LTS.
Kernel 5.15.0-88-generic

I'm using zerotier network to connect to my server. Everything worked fine and then maybe I changed something, maybe no, but when I tried update it didn't work. Curl just freezes, apt cannot connect to anything, network timeout. I think it might use wrong network, but configs looks fine.

Also there where some additional postrouting settings for 443,80 and 3000 ports, and I deleted it because thought it could be the issue. Maybe I added it earlier, dont know. Also cannot see webinterface of 192.168.2.1. It's 100% on, cause nmap shows open ports, and I did connect before, but now cannot see it using curl.

nslookup, ping works, everything else - no.

My system is ubuntu linux.
Time is ok

```
sudo iptables -L -n
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  10.1.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for MicroK8s pods */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.1.0.0/16          /* generated for MicroK8s pods */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

here eno4 is my main netowrk interface, and zth6rjzumt is zerotier network

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:18:77:31:40:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0
3: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:18:77:31:40:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eno4
       valid_lft 322sec preferred_lft 322sec
5: zth6rjzumt: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:f9:1e:bc:f7:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.243.145.1/16 brd 10.243.255.255 scope global zth6rjzumt
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b3:c3:6a:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: cali1fc61b2214e@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-1a155d71-1741-922e-9e68-ef823c07b36d
27: cali79a33944d72@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-c52d1bb3-8de5-87e5-efee-b3201ca1f0c6
30: vxlan.calico: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 66:19:5e:5e:13:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.70.192/32 scope global vxlan.calico
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

DNS seems to be ok and should be ok

also tried to disable ipv6, but it doesn't change anything.

I also did change router configs, but firewall looks ok, and I'm able to ping, so it shoudln't be the issue.

ip route

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eno4 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.2 metric 100
blackhole 10.1.70.192/26 proto 80
10.1.70.248 dev cali1fc61b2214e scope link
10.1.70.249 dev cali79a33944d72 scope link
10.243.0.0/16 dev zth6rjzumt proto kernel scope link src 10.243.145.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.2.0/24 dev eno4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2 metric 100
192.168.2.1 dev eno4 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.2 metric 100
```

ip addr show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:18:77:31:40:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0
3: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:18:77:31:40:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eno4
       valid_lft 486sec preferred_lft 486sec
5: zth6rjzumt: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:f9:1e:bc:f7:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.243.145.1/16 brd 10.243.255.255 scope global zth6rjzumt
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b3:c3:6a:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: vxlan.calico: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 66:19:5e:5e:13:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.70.192/32 scope global vxlan.calico
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
46: cali1fc61b2214e@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-4aa48182-009f-e169-b53b-74e75be994f1
47: cali79a33944d72@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1350 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-920a93e9-8949-9f1a-a296-cbc045c3b3ff
```

Comment: Well, it's ubuntu server, only CLI, 22.04.3 LTS. Kernel 5.15.0-88-generic. Hope it helps